# Can I build interpolated strings in Docker Compose with host names?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to make an environment variable, in Docker Compose file with the address of a REST service, something like
this: 
`rest_api_url: http://rest_service_name:5000`

Docker Compose is able to resolve the IP address of the service, if the variable looks like this, without any surrounding strings:
 `rest_api_url: rest_service_name`

Is there a way to interpolate the resolved IP address into a string? I've only found `${}` which only works for existing environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do this, accessing the URL as `http://rest_service_name:5000/` should actually work inside the containers without the need to explicitly resolve the IP in the variable first, as the docker containers can access each other with the name.

Here is an example YAML for a service I had, it passes the URL of a service to the other through environment variable, and it worked for me:

```
version: "3"

services:
  config-server:
    image: configuration-server
    restart: "no"
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - test

  service:
    depends_on:
      - config-server
    image: the_service_image
    restart: "no"
    ports:
        - "8084:8084"
    networks:
      - test
    environment:
      config-server-url: "http://config-server:8081/config"

networks:
  test:
```